# Call a changing variable from outside the function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, nouislider

```
var slider = document.getElementById('test5');
noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [1366],
    step: 1,
    range: {
        'min': 200,
        'max': 1920
    },
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0,
        postfix: 'px',
    })
});

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myWidth', function ($scope) {
    $scope.width = inputFormat.value;

    $scope.$watch('width', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('Old:' + oldValue);
        console.log('New:' + newValue);
    });
    console.log($scope.width + ' - scope width');
});
var inputFormat = document.getElementById('input-format');
editorContainer = document.getElementById('editorContainer');
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
    inputFormat.value = values[handle];
    //$(editorContainer).css('width', values[handle]);
});
inputFormat.addEventListener('change', function(){
    slider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
});
```

I am having a problem getting the value of inputFormat on a constant basis. What happens is that I run my webpage/application and the $scope.width variable gets the first value of inputFormat and then stops. It doesn't continue to get the value after the value of inputFormat has changed. So my question is **how would I call the inputFormat variable in a way that the $scope.width variable gets updated?** I am new to angular and javascript, and hopefully you all can understand my question. Thanks for the help!

Here is the part of the html where I call $scope.width:

```
<div class="" <!--id="editorContainer"--> style="position: absolute; top: 10px;    bottom: 10px; right: 10px; left: 10px; width: {{width}};"
```

Comment: this defeats the purpose of angular. You should just be using two-way binding. lookup ng-model

Comment: Alright so I tried using two way data binding and it binds. But when the value of the width changes, the width of the div I am assigning the ng-model({{width}}) to doesn't update or change with it. It gets the value once and then stops and doesn't continue to update. Do you have any ideas on how to change this? Again I am new to angular so if something doesn't seem logically sound that is why, I am still learning the syntax and the logic behind angular.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) and then just change $scope.width..